# There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server

Tags: postgresql, ssis, odbc, devart

Please help, as I can not seem to upload/insert data from my SQL Server to my SSH Postgre and I get this error:

> **There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server**

I checked the connection using SSMS and a program I designed and they work fine using the ODBC but SSIS is not working.

Inserting data into PostgreSQL using SSIS and ODBC.

Comment: Is it working locally but not on the server?  Then sounds like some drivers/.dll s are missing on server that you have locally.

Comment: It is working normally, I can connect to the server online, and select the tables but executing the data flow gives me that error, the ODBC works fine on SSMS as a linked server and also on a program I designed but not on SSIS